# how to set the log level at runtime in slf4j easily?

Tags: java, logging, slf4j

related:

[How to change slf4j level at runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11145090/how-to-change-slf4j-level-at-runtime?s=1|2.8858)    [SLF4J debugging level configuration + Logging framework integration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5924176/slf4j-debugging-level-configuration-logging-framework-integration?s=3|1.7988)    [Set Dynamic Console Logging Level Using SLF4J](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15264240/set-dynamic-console-logging-level-using-slf4j?s=6|1.5636)    [Setting log level of message at runtime in slf4j](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2621701/setting-log-level-of-message-at-runtime-in-slf4j?s=8|1.5200)    [How to dynamically change log level in SLF4j OR Log4J](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13442967/how-to-dynamically-change-log-level-in-slf4j-or-log4j?s=18|1.1769)

is it possible to do this *easily*?

edit: looks like you can't do that. one must fool around with the underlying implementation. i am using the simple jar.

thanks

Comment: Do you want to change the level for the current running application or do you want to persist the change also for the next application start? Is it a desktop application or does it run inside an application server?

Comment: "Easily" is subjective -- in what way are all those answers you cited not "easy"?

Comment: just wanted to change it programmaticaly at run time. none of the answers to the other questions let me do it easily without a lot of trouble.

Answer (score 0):

I do it this way, but there are others:

```
 String tmpName = "newLogConfig.xml"
    try (InputStream defaultIs = Log4jReconfigurator.class.getResourceAsStream()) {
      logger.warn("Using log4j configuration " + tmpName);
      new DOMConfigurator().doConfigure(is, LogManager.getLoggerRepository());
    } catch (IOException e) {
      logger.error("Failed to reconfigure log configuration", e);
    }
```

I provide predefined logging templates, and this allows you to load them at runtime.

Comment: i am using the simple jar. so it looks like i have to fool with the concrete stuff.

Answer (score 0):

You cant configure SLF4J, you need to configure the concrete logging framework SLF4J is configured to work with.